# full width squarespace product block

Tags: squarespace

I'm struggling to find a way to adjust the width of a product block. Website's page is dachshund-crane-s64k.squarespace.com/nouvelle-page (password is 'password'). The width for the variants and the add to cart button is automatically set, yet I would like the whole thing to occupy 100% of the space so the block is equal to the photo on the left. [Here is a screenshot of the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zshe5.png). Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the following Custom CSS via the [CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor) in order to widen the `select` elements and the button to the full width of the parent element:

```
select[data-variant-option-name] {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.sqs-add-to-cart-button {
  width: 100% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```